# Android adb find and click button

Tags: android, adb, python-tesseract

I am developing a shell script to test a website using ADB and I am trying to click a button, but the button is not always in the same coordinates.

How can I locate coordinates of the button by the text and then click it?

I am reaching the website with the default browser.

Thanks.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71199716/edit) your post to include where the website appears: in your own app or a browser.

Comment: I don't think testing web sites using pure adb is a good idea. Better use [Chrome remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) or something like that.

Comment: The thing is @Robert, is that I have to test some apps too, that's why I need to locate buttons, links, etc in the screen, so i can be able to click it in a automated way.

Comment: The use some framework like appium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished using [OpenCV](https://opencv.org)

What I did was to take a screenshot of the button and then using that image to locate the button itself in the screen.

Thanks.